# What is a media guard?

Tags: hydronic

I am building a simple aquaponic system by learning from this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lqe3IqPisns

- at 1:24, we will a ***media guard*** is implemented; which is basically fat tube with lots of holes drilled through.

I think it functions as a filter to keep objects that is larger than the holes from being drained to the lower level.

I am not sure if I interpreted its purpose correctly.

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: Media guard is a guy you pay to make sure no reporters have access to your aquaponic system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it functions as a filter to keep the [growing media](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B012TUG4J4) from making its way to the lower level.

The holes would be smaller then the media, the holes allow the water to drain out but not the media. (*the "media" in this case are  the small clay balls that hold the roots of the plants in suspension facilitating an oxygenated water  environment*.)